# How do I specify Command on Button when I'm using a Template in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, command, controltemplate

I have a `Button` template to define what my edit button should look like:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="EditButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
     <Button Style="{StaticResource GrayOutButtonStyle}" >
        <Image x:Name="editImage" Source="{StaticResource EditIcon}" />
     </Button>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I want to declare the `Command` in the XAML where I create the button (not in the template).  But when I set the `Command` attribute in the `Button`, it's being ignored:

```
<Button Template="{StaticResource EditButton}" 
        Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}, Path=EditCommand}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
```

What's wrong with my syntax?

(Note: If I remove the template from this button then the `Command` works, so it's something about using a template that's messing it up.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does your `Button` template include another `Button`? That makes no sense and would suffer from a StackOverflow if your template was applied implicitly. It should just be the `Image`, in which case your command should work.

To be clear, what's happening is you have an outer `Button` which correctly has the `ICommand` applied to it. However, it's being rendered as another `Button` with an `Image` inside it. Hence, when you click the `Image`, you're actually clicking the *inner* `Button`, which has no `ICommand` associated with it. The outer Button never "sees" the click, so it never executes the command.

Your only other option, which I wouldn't recommend, but should work, is to have the inner button bind to the properties on the outer button:

```
<ControlTemplate ...>
    <Button Command="{TemplateBinding Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding CommandParameter}" ...>
        <Image .../>
    </Button>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Because if I remove the Button from the template then I _only_ get an image, it does not display inside of the button look.  I want my button's appearance to be a button with that image and to apply the GrayOutButtonStyle.

Since the template is keyed, i'd think it wouldn't apply recursively - that it only is applied if you explicitly declare Template={Static Resource EditButton}.  Is that not correct?

Comment: It does work with this in the template (had to mod the CommandParamater to just Binding): <Button Style="{StaticResource GrayOutButtonStyle}" Command="{TemplateBinding Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" >

But if this isn't the right way to template a button that looks like a button with an image, would still like to understand that.  thanks!

Comment: If all you need is an image in your button, the "right way" is to not template at all and just declare a `Button` with an `Image` as its content. Otherwise, a good place to start is by copying the existing `Button` template and altering it. Blend is the best tool for this. XAMLPadX may suffice.

Comment: Not all I need for the button, and I need it in several places.

Comment: @Abby: DataTemplate might suffice. It's hard to answer your question when you don't give all the requisite information up front ;)

Comment: Sorry i was trying not to overcomplicate the question of why the command wasn't working with pages of xaml.  I'll start another question as would like to understand this!

Answer (score 0):

Another option to refer to the command is relative binding as below:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Button Command="{Binding Path=Command, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}">
                <Image... />
            </Button>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```